# Constructor type not found

Tags: c#, enterprise-library

What I am doing:
I am taking the Microsoft Enterprise Library 4.1 and attempting to expand upon it using a few derived classes.

I have created a **MyLogEntry**, **MyFormatter**, and **MyTraceListener** which derive from their respective base classes when you remove the "My" from their names.

What my problem is:
Everything compiles fine. When I go to run a test using **Logger.Write(logEntry)** it errors right after it initializes **MyTraceListener** with an error message:

*"The current build operation (... EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.LogWriter, null]) failed: Constructor on type '**MyLogging.MyFormatter**' not found. (Strategy type ConfiguredObjectStrategy, index 2)*

I figured it was something to do with the constructor so I tried removing it, add it, and adding a call to the base class **LogFormatter**. Nothing has worked.

Does anyone have insight into this problem? Is it maybe a reference issue? Bad App.config configuration?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is you did not provide the right constructor.  In order to inject your custom formatter you need to provide a constructor similar to the below

```
public MyFormatter(NameValueCollection collection){

 }
```

For more information see this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc309275.aspx)

Comment: Thank you Nix that was the problem exactly.